# mscorsw causing fan to spin like hell when idle

Tags: windows-7, cpu, fan

So it has been happening for some time, whenever I go away from the computer, after 5 minutes I hear the fan going full speed. When I come back it stops immediately.

I managed to find out what was causing this by leaving the task manager window open. There it appears that some app called "mscorsw" is using a lot of cpu when the computer is idle. How can I stop this madness? plz help me

Comment: You mean 'mscorsvw'? Another 'mscorsvvw' is actually a malware.

Comment: yes. next to it it says: .NET Runtime Optimization Service. wtf is this and why is it running every time i go away from he pc?

Comment: The runtime optimization is an intense process, so MS choose to do it when you PC is idle. the bigger question with your fan, is why is your PC overheating to the extent that the fan needs to spin up. a stable build will run at 100% for quite some time before it needs to spin up the fans, so I recommend cleaning your box, replacing any dead fans (your PC should have at least 2), and monitoring the system temperature when under a load. if it heats up quickly and your box is clean, you probably need to reseat your heatsink, or replace failing/insufficient cooling components.

Comment: but it's a new laptop. I had windows 7 32 bit on it for like a week and didn't have this problem. This started to happen after I upgraded to the 64 bit version :|. I think the fan spins because that thing uses 100% cpu or something

Comment: well, fan isn't tied to usage, but temperature. that is worrisome. Did you install ALL the drivers from your manufacturer, including the Chipset INF update (if intel) and any power management drivers? The BIOS controls fanstate, and windows can use the ACPI (Advanced configuration and Power Interface) to communicate with and control the bios but it requires all the drivers be installed. if you just reinstalled using a non-OEM disk from the manufacturer, this is likely the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2005/04/27/412838.aspx

Try:  **ngen.exe executequeueditems**

The mscorsw is part of Microsoft .NET.

The source above covers the matter in detail, however, something else could be using cause it to do this also.

Comment: I tried that in cmd and it says the command is not recognized

Comment: I'm assuming your issue is with .Net 2. let us know if its a differant .net framework. Before you run the command, enter `cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ `, and it should run correctly. the instructions in the blog use the Visual Studio command prompt, which uses different environment values. You can also disable the service itself in `services.msc` by selecting the service(s) 'Microsoft .Net Framework NGEN vX.XXXXXXx64' that have a start type of Automatic or Manual, double click it, and change its start type to 'Disabled'. This will opt you out of optimization.